# Sampling continuous function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sampling

I'm new to matlab, and in this academic exercise they asked us to do a sampling from a continuous function.

My original functions are:

```
x = sin(pi * t);
y = cos(2 * pi * t / 3);
z = x + y - 2;
```

In the interval

```
t = -8:0.001:8;
```

Then they asked us to make a sampling, `z(n)`, of `z` with a period of `Ts=0.01` seconds.

My idea was to save in a new vector the values of `z`, jumping through `z` ten by ten positions:

```
n = numel(z);
Zd = z(0:10:z);
```

This idea came from the fact that 0.01 seconds is ten times less accurate then the first 'continuous' interval `t`. But matlab says that this is not possible and gives me the error:

```
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Can somebody give me some hint on this?

Comment: MATLAB index starts from `1` not `0`.

Comment: OMG !
I just 'wasted' a question on SO with this. 

Shame on me. 

Thanks!

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 2 @Memming said, matlab indexes start at 1 and not 0, and that was my problem.

Thanks.